# Populate with two models mongoose node.js?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose as orm and mongodb as database and express framework in node.js to build a lms learning management system app

The app has two models which are teacher and student

The problem is that I have an array which contains object ids for both of them mixed

And I want to populate each field according to its model

Something like:

```
const array = [
   ' teacherobjectid',
   ' studentobjectid',
   ....
]
```

I want to populate the student object id to the student model and the teacher to teacher model

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: How do you distinguish which is the studentId and which is the teacherId?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't do that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
let my_array = ["student_id", "teacher_id"]


let students = Student.find({_id: {$in: my_array}})

let teachers = Teachers.find({_id: {$in:my_array}})
```

but this is not good idea , cuase for each id you must get two queries.

try to use **ref** in your model schema,for seperating id entities. if your array comes from some mongo collection :

```
student_ids: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Student",
    }],

teacher_ids: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Teacher",
    }],
```